# Значения ячеек в столбце JTable

Tags: java, swing

Как найти значения в ячейках одного столбца Ячейки(строки) не выделены

Есть Jtable с 5 столбцами и 100 строками Нужно узнать значения всех 100 ячеек находящийся во втором столбце (загнать в коллекцию)

```
table.setModel(Date.queryА());
/************************************/
public static Model queryA() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Model M = new Model();
    Connection cn = Conection.conectar();
    QueryStringBuilder query = new QueryStringBuilder();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
           query.append(0,"SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM table");  
        M.setDataSource(rs);
        M.setEditable(new Integer[]{0,1,2,3,4,5});
    } finally {
        if (cn != null) {
            cn.close();
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
    } 
    return M;
}
```

**Model**

```
package main;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author users
 */
public class Model extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ArrayList<Integer> columnEdit = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Class> columnTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getRowCount() {
        synchronized (data) {
            return data.size();
        }
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        synchronized (data) {
            return data.get(row).get(col);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getData() {
        synchronized (data) {
            return data;
        }
    }
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames.get(col);
    }

    public int getColumnIndexOf(String name) {
        synchronized (columnNames) {
            return columnNames.indexOf(name);
        }
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
        return columnTypes.get(col);
    }

    private void setColumnClass (int row, Class C1) {
        synchronized(columnTypes) {
            columnTypes.set(row, C1);
        }
    }

    public void setEditable(Integer[] id) {
        synchronized(columnEdit) {
            columnEdit.addAll(Arrays.asList(id));
        }
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return columnEdit.contains(col);
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object obj, int row, int col) {
        synchronized (data) {
            data.get(row).set(col, obj);
        }
    }

    public void setDataSource(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        columnNames.clear();
        columnTypes.clear();
        data.clear();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            columnNames.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1));
            Class type = Class.forName(rsmd.getColumnClassName(i + 1));
            if (type==java.sql.Timestamp.class) {
                columnTypes.add(String.class);
            } else {
                columnTypes.add(type);
            }
        }
        fireTableStructureChanged();
        while (rs.next()) {
            ArrayList rowData = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                if (columnTypes.get(i) == String.class){
                    rowData.add(rs.getString(i + 1));}
                else{
                    rowData.add(rs.getObject(i + 1));}
            } synchronized (data) {
                data.add(rowData);
                this.fireTableRowsInserted(data.size() - 1, data.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getRowIndex(String columnName, Object value) {
        synchronized (data) {
            int column = getColumnIndexOf(columnName);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                Object curentValue = data.get(i).get(column);
                if (curentValue.equals(value)) {
                    return i;
                }
            } return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы заходите не стой стороны. у таблицы есть модель и вот с ней и надо работать. она хранит все данные. как у вас данные попадают в **JTable**?

Comment: запросами mssql

Comment: как вы добавляете данные в таблицу? покажите код в волпросе.

Comment: забросил код сверху

Comment: еще добавьте код класса **Model**

Comment: добавил код сверху

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63100/discussion-between-user-and-mikhail-vaysman).

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте вашу модель доступной в обработчике события, где вы работает с данными, а затем сможете получить список из желаемых ячеек.

```
private List<Object> doSomethig(Model m) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ArrayList<Object> row: m.getData()) {
        list.add(row.get(1));
    }
    return list;
}
```